# Block height for v6 fork

Tags: hard-fork, block-height

What is the block height and approximate date for the v6 Monero fork? Has there been a [decision to change the targeted block height](https://monerobase.com/wiki/DevMeeting_2017-09-03) based on discussions to keep the fork near Sept 21st despite a recent increase in network hashrate that otherwise might cause it to come about 5 days sooner?

> Due to much more hashrate, the intended hardfork date of Sept 21 2017, may be closer to Sept 16 2017.
>   Discussion is ongoing on whether the hard fork block number should be adjusted to something closer to Sept 21st.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The v6 fork is planned for block 1400000, which is on or about the 16th of september. Hash rate increase had little effect on the projected date, as can be seen in the patch (https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2335/commits/2147859ac9d4660d0cc7736c8524fb2b48e9fbb2), so the discussion above is incorrect. Apparently the 21 date comes from a note in the README.md file which had not been grounded in anything.

Comment: And block 1400000 was grounded in.... ?

Comment: Arbitrary, to be close to mid september while being easy to remember, which was a criticism leveled at the previous fork height.