# Download Link Monero 0.11.0 (Helium Hydra) broken

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, linux

This link ([64-bit Linux GUI](https://downloads.getmonero.org/gui/monero-gui-linux-x64-v0.11.0.0.tar.bz2)) is broken. Also the 32-bit GUI has an invalid link. Where can I get the correct file(s)?

Comment: This should either be closed due to its timeliness / time delimited nature. You could perhaps modify it to something like "Where is the best place to download monero binaries?" the best answer, maybe, will always be the github release page.

Comment: Link is recoverd again, so this will be closed

Comment: I'm flagging as: **Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GUI links on the [download](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) page were temporarily broken on purpose as the prior Beta 2 GUI was about to be updated in advance of the [v6 fork](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5951/block-height-for-v6-fork). The [Helium Hydra](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5972/what-changes-are-in-the-monero-0-11-0-0-release) command line release became available before the graphical user interface. As of the time of this edit, the GUI links on the [download](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) page are now available too.

The now outdated GUI Beta 2 release files are [still available here](https://getmonero.org/2017/03/29/monero-gui-beta-2-released.html) just like other [archived links to prior major releases.](https://getmonero.org/blog/tags/releases.html)

Comment: Looks like the update has become available right now

Answer (score 1):

Check here for the CLI: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases and

here for the GUI: https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/releases

I guess it's not ready yet as of now.

Comment: Only CLI versions via the link you provided

Comment: Sry, updated but looks like it's not released yet