# Desktop GUI wallet not syncing

Tags: synchronization, update

I've received two transactions on this wallet previously.  The last time I opened this wallet it would not completely sync up, just stopped.  I tried the suggestions on one post here, first deleted p2pstate.bin, then changed --block-sync-size 10, then deleted data.mdb and attempted to resync from scratch.  It got to over 99% but is stuck at 2889 blocks remaining (not sure how to figure which block that is).  Do I need to update my wallet, it was downloaded from the getmonero site in Aug.  If I update, does it keep the original keys etc. so I keep the transactions? because there is one in progress that I haven't received yet - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It got to over 99% but is stuck at 2889 blocks remaining (not sure how to figure which block that is) Do I need to update my wallet, it was downloaded from the getmonero site in Aug

Based on the above and the approximate timing of your question it sounds like you are stuck on [block 1,400,000](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5951/block-height-for-v6-fork) which was the block height of the [0.11.0.0 "Helium Hydra" fork](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5972/what-changes-are-in-the-monero-0-11-0-0-release). You will need to update using [these instructions](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/how-do-i-upgrade-my-software-to-v0-11-0-0)

> If I update, does it keep the original keys etc. so I keep the transactions?

Yes, if you follow the instructions in this [link](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/5972/what-changes-are-in-the-monero-0-11-0-0-release) all of that data will be retained

Comment: Thanks, worked perfect! Sorry to ask, now that the wallet is synced up, should I now delete the folder for the previous XMR version?  I see my prior version at C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\monero-gui-win-x64-v0.10.3.1  and the new version just under it at C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\monero-gui-win-x64-v0.11.0.0.  I assume opening the new wallet just pulled some data from the prior version and that it doesn't need to do that again?

Comment: @gary  Although there is no pressing need to do so, it is fine to delete the old GUI version. These are the only wallet files you need: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/what-data-do-the-wallet-files-contain. Always save you mnemonic seed (securely offline) for backup recovery reasons